# How do I add a new ATM account and change user's PIN in this program?

Tags: java, class, constructor, jframe

Our professor gave us an activity to make an ATM program and I have done most of its functions already except from creating a new ATM account and changing the PIN number. I can only output that there has been a new account created or the PIN has been changed but I don't know how to actually do them. When the user wants to create a new account, he will enter his first name, last name, card number, pin code, and balance (all in String except balance which is in double) then the program should record that new account so you can use it to inquire balance, deposit, or withdraw. Here is my code for those two ATM functions:

```
public class ATM_Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int f=8;
int l=8;
int n=8;
int p=8;
int a=8;

String fname[] = new String [f];
String lname[] = new String [l];
String cardno[] = new String [n];
String pinno[] = new String [p];
double balance[] = new double [a];



public ATM_Frame() {


    initComponents();

    btnClr.setEnabled(true);
    btnNewAcc.setEnabled(false);
    btnInq2.setEnabled(false);
    btnDep2.setEnabled(false);
    btnWdw2.setEnabled(false);
    txtOutput.setEditable(false);


    fname[0] = "Gudrun"; 
    fname[1] = "Denis";
    fname[2] = "Tamiko";

    lname[0] = "Schlender"; 
    lname[1] = "Petrov";
    lname[2] = "Tanaka";

    cardno[0] = "5023"; 
    cardno[1] = "1821";
    cardno[2] = "9931";

    pinno[0] = "0000"; 
    pinno[1] = "1111";
    pinno[2] = "2222";

    balance[0] = 5290; 
    balance[1] = 3600;
    balance[2] = 10250;

}

private void btnNewAccActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    ButtonSound();
    String fname = txtfName.getText();
    String lname = txtlName.getText();
    String cardno = txtcardNo.getText();
    String pinno = txtpinNo.getText();
    double bal = Double.parseDouble(txtBal.getText());

    ATM_NewAcc a = new ATM_NewAcc(fname,lname,cardno,pinno,bal);
    txtOutput.setText("" + a.toString());
}     

private void btnChangePinActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    ButtonSound();
    String fname = txtfName.getText();
    String lname = txtlName.getText();
    String cardno = txtcardNo.getText();
    String pinno = txtpinNo.getText();
    String newpin = txtNewPin.getText();

    if(fname.equals("Gudrun") && lname.equals("Schlender") && cardno.equals("5023") && pinno.equals("0000"))
    {

        ATM_ChangePIN d = new ATM_ChangePIN(fname,lname,cardno,pinno,newpin);
        txtOutput.setText("" + d.toString());
}

    else if(fname.equals("Denis") && lname.equals("Petrov") && cardno.equals("1821") && pinno.equals("1111"))
    {
        ATM_ChangePIN d = new ATM_ChangePIN(fname,lname,cardno,pinno,newpin);
        txtOutput.setText("" + d.toString());
}

    else if(fname.equals("Tamiko") && lname.equals("Tanaka") && cardno.equals("9931") && pinno.equals("2222"))
    {
        ATM_ChangePIN d = new ATM_ChangePIN(fname,lname,cardno,pinno,newpin);
        txtOutput.setText("" + d.toString());
}

    else if(fname.equals("") || lname.equals("") || cardno.equals("") || pinno.equals("") && txtBal.equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill out all necessary fields.", null, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }

    else 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The information you entered is invalid.", null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        txtfName.setText("");
        txtlName.setText("");
        txtcardNo.setText("");
        txtpinNo.setText("");
        txtNewPin.setText("");
        txtBal.setText("");
    }
}
```

The class for the New Account:

```
public class ATM_NewAcc 
{
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String cardno;
private String pinno;
private double balance;

public ATM_NewAcc()
{
   fname = "";
   lname = "";
   cardno = "";
   pinno = "";
   balance = 0;
}

 public ATM_NewAcc(String first, String last, String card, String pin, double bal)
{
    fname = first;
    lname = last;
    cardno = card;
    pinno = pin;
    balance = bal;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
        return "NEW BANK ACCOUNT CREATED!"
                + "\nName: " + fname + " " + lname 
                + "\nAccount Number: " + cardno 
                + "\nPIN Code: " + pinno
                + "\nBalance: " + balance;
} 
}
```

The class for the Change PIN:

```
private void btnChangePinActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    ButtonSound();
    String fname = txtfName.getText();
    String lname = txtlName.getText();
    String cardno = txtcardNo.getText();
    String pinno = txtpinNo.getText();
    String newpin = txtNewPin.getText();

    if(fname.equals("Gudrun") && lname.equals("Schlender") && cardno.equals("5023") && pinno.equals("0000"))
    {

        ATM_ChangePIN d = new ATM_ChangePIN(fname,lname,cardno,pinno,newpin);
        txtOutput.setText("" + d.toString());
}

    else if(fname.equals("Denis") && lname.equals("Petrov") && cardno.equals("1821") && pinno.equals("1111"))
    {
        ATM_ChangePIN d = new ATM_ChangePIN(fname,lname,cardno,pinno,newpin);
        txtOutput.setText("" + d.toString());
}

    else if(fname.equals("Tamiko") && lname.equals("Tanaka") && cardno.equals("9931") && pinno.equals("2222"))
    {
        ATM_ChangePIN d = new ATM_ChangePIN(fname,lname,cardno,pinno,newpin);
        txtOutput.setText("" + d.toString());
}

    else if(fname.equals("") || lname.equals("") || cardno.equals("") || pinno.equals("") && txtBal.equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill out all necessary fields.", null, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }

    else 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The information you entered is invalid.", null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        txtfName.setText("");
        txtlName.setText("");
        txtcardNo.setText("");
        txtpinNo.setText("");
        txtNewPin.setText("");
        txtBal.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you provided it seems that you would have to put the input data into the arrays fname[], lname[], etc.

Maybe there is a method "addAccount(ATM_NewAcc acc)" or something similar, that puts the data from an ATM_NewAcc object into the arrays? What happens when there are more than 8 users? ;)

Edit: Something like this?

```
public class Acc
{
    private String name;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Acc(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Atm
{
    private String[] users = new String[8];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Atm atm = new Atm();
        atm.users[0] = "Test1";
        atm.addUser(new Acc("Test2"));
        atm.printUsers();
    }

    private void printUsers()
    {
        for(String s : users)
        {
            if(s != null)
            {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addUser(Acc acc)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < users.length; ++i)
        {
            if(users[i] == null)
            {
                users[i] = acc.getName();
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Too many accounts");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there should be a loop for the adding of accounts but I don't know how to do that.

I just set a limit to the number of accounts available including the 3 accounts that is already included. I will put an condition and an error message after I know how to do the adding of accounts.

Comment: How do I make it read the information (first name, last name, card number, pin code) that the user has to input before creating an account?